# Do angels pray for us?

Tags: prayer, intercession, angels

I was reading about [henotheism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henotheism#Christianity) and it hinted at the fact that some Christians believe that angels are intercessors.

Quite simply, do angels pray for us?  Can we ask angels for intercession?

Comment: If you can reconcile the two answers you got, then I recommend you move to Northern Ireland and help them out with their problems.

Comment: As Peter mentioned, this answers that this question has received come from two different backgrounds.  This shows that this question isn't appropriately scoped and [fails the quality standards](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/725/).  Because of this, I'm closing this question.  The only other alternative would be to refine the question, asking from a particular viewpoint, which would invalidate one of these answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the St. Michael prayer:

> Glorious St. Michael the archangel protect us in battle be our safeguard against the wickedness and snares of the Devil, may God rebuke him we humbly pray and do thou oh prince of the heavenly host, by the power of God, cast into Hell Satan and all the evil spirits who prowl about the earth seeking the ruin of souls.

Pope Leo XIII added it to the end of one of the old liturgies around the turn of the 20th century.  Catholics don't pray it after Mass any more, but the prayer is still a very popular (and efficacious) one, should you need a demon cast into Hell.

And this is the Guardian Angel prayer:

> Angel of God, my guardian dear, to whom God's love commits me near, ever this day/night be at my side to light to guard to rule and guide.

Most Catholics ask angels to protect us, but we know we're asking them to do what Jesus (the One Mediator) committed them to do.

Comment: Wait... so the archangel is a saint?  It thought all saints were human once.

Comment: @Richard, the universal Church encompasses the entire communion of saints, every soul created by God for His glory.  Angels have no body, but are nonetheless in the beatific vision (in God's presence in Heaven) and therefore saints.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with Wayne Grudem who cites 1 Tim. 2:5 in answering this question.

> For there is one God, and there is one mediator between God and men,
>   the man Christ Jesus,
>
> The Holy Bible : English standard version. 2001 (1 Ti 2:5). Wheaton:
>   Standard Bible Society.

Based on this we see clearly that Christ is the only mediator between Christians and God the Father. Additionally, Paul calls out the worship of angels as false doctrine in [Col. 2:18](http://biblia.com/bible/esv/Col2.18). While praying to angels arguably may not be worship, in my mind the line is far too fine to mess around with.

Comment: So, according to this stance, the saints are not our intercessors either?

Comment: What if an angel were to pray in Jesus name for someone just like we humans do?

Comment: @richard that's certainly my understanding

Comment: @richard Yes, that is the Protestant theological point-of-view.

Comment: @caleb I think the difference is whether we ask an angel to pray for us as opposed to an angel praying of his own volition

Comment: @caleb We don't know the answer to that. We do know that angels are intelligent and can make moral judgements. As far as I am aware the Bible references angels praising and worshiping God directly from around His throne, but not praying to Him.

Comment: @blundin with [Episcopalians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Episcopal_Church_(United_States)) being the odd-one-out?  ;)

Comment: @Richard Good point. As far as I know they are the only ones who have a theology of saints as intercessors. My oversight on that one. If there are other Protestant denominations that share that same POV, I am not aware of them. But then again, I'm human and greatly fallible. :)

Comment: @waggers What if I ask my friend to pray for me vs. he prays without being asked?

Comment: @caleb I think I'd better think this through again...

Comment: @Caleb If I may offer an answer, I think the difference lies in the God-created differences between angels and ourselves. Angels were created by God for specific purposes, as messengers, worshipers and heavenly beings. This differs from the purpose humanity serves in the great story of redemption. We are not analogous. Ultimately we need an intercessor in heaven as we cannot directly approach God, and Paul tells us that Jesus is the only one. Whether I am praying for you, or you are praying for me, for our prayers to be heard someone must intercede for us. That is where Christ comes in.