# In reference to humans becoming Angels?

Tags: angels, ecclesiastes

How can humans become Angels if (Ecclesiastes 12:7) says "and dust returns to the ground it came from, and the Spirit returns to God who gave it" and (Ecclesiastes 3:20)  "All go to the same place; all come from dust, and to dust all return."

Comment: This could be clarified if we understood where you were getting the "humans become angels" idea. What denominations/groups of doctrines believe this?

Comment: Most Christians would say that humans cannot become angels. What makes you think they can?

Answer (score 5):

[People don't become angels](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1955/can-humans-become-angels?rq=1).  No one* ever said they did.

1. Angelos (Messenger) is [a job](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/15130/1039), not a species. Angels are God's messengers, differentiated from [prophets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophet), in that they have spoken with God face to face.
2. The most well known angel species (Cherubim and Seraphim) [are different species than homo sapiens](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/2918/297)
3. The [source of the myth](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/19672/what-is-source-of-myth-that-the-deceased-become-angels?lq=1) that people become angels is based on a misinterpretation that just isn't held.

---

*By "no one" of course I mean no one in a position to speak intelligently as to the scripture or traditions of the church.  This is a folk belief, not a doctrine of any recognized denomination.

Comment: Might additionally be worth mentioning that it is not entirely clear if the author of Ecclesiates thinks that there is an afterlife of any kind (Ecclesiastes 9:5).

Comment: If you say angels are a species, then what species? Please remember species is a very specific term. Maybe look it up first or use another word like 'entity'. Well, thanks for the giggle anyways.

Comment: The species is merely identified as not Homo sapiens. If you follow my links you will find the non-Linnean names (Cherubim and Seraphim).